# Yii2: How to get records which its attribute is in an array?

Tags: php, yii2

I built a website with Yii2 and I tried to get the records which their categories are available. I have got the available categories and stored them in an array. But it returns nothing when I tried to use the 'in' condition for the next query. I am sure that the database records are correct.

```
// Get active categories
$active_cat = Category::find()
              ->where(['status' => SystemCode::STATUS_ACTIVE])
              ->andwhere(['is_deleted' => 0])
              ->select(['id'])
              ->asArray()
              ->all();

// Get available articles
$query = Articles::find()
         ->where(['in', 'cat_id', $active_cat]);
```

Comment: what is result of `$active_cat` array? To get article query result you need to add `all()`.

Comment: Can you add your `Category` and `Articles` model? If they are related you could use the relation to get them without a `foreach` or two independet queries. By the way, is not common to have a plural model name `Articles` any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `all()` to get list of categories, which will give you array of rows in format:

```
[
    ['id' => 1],
    // ...
],
```

But for your next query you need a flat list of IDs - you can achieve this by using [`column()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail) method instead:

```
// Get active categories
$active_cat = Category::find()
              ->where(['status' => SystemCode::STATUS_ACTIVE])
              ->andWhere(['is_deleted' => 0])
              ->select(['id'])
              ->column();

// Get available articles
$query = Articles::find()
         ->where(['in', 'cat_id', $active_cat]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a **one-to-many** relation between `Articles` and `Category` defined as follows:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class, ['id' => 'cat_id']);
}
```

You can get all `Articles` records where `status = SYSTEM_CODE::STATUS_ACTIVE` like this:

```
$articles = $query = Articles::find()->joinWith('category')
    ->where([
        'category.status' => SYSTEM_CODE::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        'category.is_deleted' => 0
    ])->all();
```

If, instead the relation is **many-to-many**, and it is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCategories()
{
   return $this->hasMany(
        Category::className(), 
        ['id' => 'cat_id'])->viaTable(
          'article_category', ['article_id' => 'id']
        );
}
```

Then you can get the same result like this:

```
$articles = $query = Articles::find()->joinWith('categories')
    ->where([
        'category.status' => SYSTEM_CODE::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        'category.is_deleted' => 0
    ])->all();
```

Only the name of the relation changes in the second example.

**Note** that I have made a few assumptions, like the name of the `category` table being `category`, a junction table being called `article_category` and so on, you may have to modify the examples to fit your code.

The documentation for [joinWith()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail).

Comment: This may be slower that OP's approach if you just need to list of active articles. Two separate queries may be more efficient than join.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note the return value of each method:**

- **one()**  This method returns an ActiveRecord object or null if not found.

  > [one()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface#one()-detail)       Executes query and returns a single row of result.
- **all()** This method returns a list of ActiveRecord objects or an empty array if not found

  > [all()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#all()-detail)    Executes the query and returns all results as an array. So in the `all()` method:
  >
  > ```
  > foreach($active_cat as $cat){
  >    # code...
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > Here, of course, you can access the second table by "**Relational Data**"

> [asArray()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail) Whether to return the query results in terms of arrays instead of Active Records.

**Also:**

> [yii\db\ActiveRecord::findOne()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findOne()-detail): returns a single Active Record
>   instance populated with the first row of the query result. (Returns a
>   single active record model instance by a primary key or an array of
>   column value)
>
> [yii\db\ActiveRecord::findAll()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findAll()-detail): returns an array of Active Record
>   instances populated with all query result. (a list of active record
>   models that match the specified primary key value(s) or a set of
>   column values.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do:
You have to reorganize your code:
in Categories model you have to put this function:

```
public function getActiveArticles()
{
    return $this=->hasMany(Articles::classname(), ['cat_id' => 'id'])->andWhere(['categories_table.status' => SystemCode::STATUS_ACTIVE, 'categories_table.is_deleted' => 0]);
}
```

Now you can access all articles by:

```
$active_cat = Category::find()->all();
foreach($active_cat as $cat)
{
    if($cat->activeAcrticles !== null)
    {
        foreach($cat->activeAcrticles as $article)
        {
            echo $article->name;
        }
    }
}
```